# Issue passing argument to my main using DFS - Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, stack, depth-first-search

I am trying to get this code running as fast as possible when traversing through my stack of my DFS currently the input files are like so:

> ```
> 0 2
> 2 1
> 1 4
> 4 5
> 5 6
> 10 8
> 8 9
> 9 6
> 7 6
> 3 4
> 0 1
> 3 9
> 0 4
> ```

Where my `Maze` class will tie the numbers together and create a graph for me. After the graph is created my `DFS` class runs through traversing giving one or all solutions to the .txt file submitted.I have recently altered my `Maze` class as for it to run more efficiently but am being thrown errors and the data is parsing through to my `DFS` to be outputted. My `Maze` class is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maze {

    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The main constructor that takes a String for reading maze file.
     *
     * @param file
     */
    public Maze(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int node1 = scan.nextInt();
                int node2 = scan.nextInt();
                this.connect(node1, node2);
                this.connect(node2, node1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes a unidirectional connection from node1 to node2.
     */
    private void connect(int node1, int node2) {
        if (!this.adjList.containsKey(node1)) {
            this.adjList.put(node1, new HashSet<Integer>());
        }
        this.adjList.get(node1).add(node2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a human-readable description of the adjacency lists.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj : this.adjList.entrySet()) {
            int from = adj.getKey();
            Set<Integer> to = adj.getValue();
            s.append(from).append(" connected to ").append(to).append('\n');
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set of nodes connected to a particular node.
     *
     * @param node - the node whose neighbors should be fetched
     */
    public Iterable<Integer> getadjList(int node) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(adjList.get(node));
    }

    /**
     * Demonstration of file reading.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.err.print("Enter File: ");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = scanFile.nextLine();
        Maze m = new Maze(new File(file));
        System.out.println(m);
    }

}
```

And my `DFS` looks like so.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DFS {
    //starting node, the route to the next node, has node been visited
    private int startNode; 
    private int[] route;
    private boolean[] visited;


    // 2 main arguments - Maze File & user input
    public DFS(Maze maze, int inputInt) {
        int startNode = 0;
        int goalNode = 1;
        route = new int[maze.node];
        visited = new boolean[maze.node];
        //Takes user's input and runs desired function
        if(inputInt == 1){
        findOne(maze, startNode, goalNode);
        }
        else if (inputInt == 2){
        findAll(maze, startNode, goalNode);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("input invalid. No Solution Returned");
        }
    }



    //Put path to goal in the stack
    public Stack<Integer> route(int toGoalNode) {
        if (!visited[toGoalNode]) {
            return null;
        }
        Stack<Integer> pathStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        for (int routeGoalNode = toGoalNode; routeGoalNode != startNode; routeGoalNode = route[routeGoalNode]) {
            pathStack.push(routeGoalNode);
        }
        pathStack.push(startNode);
        reverseStack(pathStack);
        return pathStack;
    }

    //Reverse the stack
    public void reverseStack(Stack<Integer> stackToBeReverse) {

        if (stackToBeReverse.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        int bottom = popBottomStack(stackToBeReverse);
        reverseStack(stackToBeReverse);
        stackToBeReverse.push(bottom);
    }

    //Pop the bottom of the stack
    private int popBottomStack(Stack<Integer> stackToBeReverse) {
        int popTopStack = stackToBeReverse.pop();
        if (stackToBeReverse.isEmpty()) {
            return popTopStack;
        } else {
            int bottomStack = popBottomStack(stackToBeReverse);
            stackToBeReverse.push(popTopStack);
            return bottomStack;
        }
    }

    //performs DFS and unsets visited to give the result of all paths 
    private void findAll(Maze maze, int node, int goal) {
        visited[node] = true; 
        if(node == goal) { 
            printPath(goal);
        } else {
            for (int con : maze.getadjList(node)) {
                if (!visited[con]) {
                    route[con] = node;
                    findAll(maze, con, goal);
                }
            }
        }
        visited[node] = false; 
    }

  //performs DFS and maintains visited marker giving only one path
    private void findOne(Maze maze, int node, int goal) {
            visited[node] = true;
            for (int con : maze.getadjList(node)) {
                if (!visited[con]) {
                    route[con] = node;
                    findOne(maze, con, goal);
                }
            }
        }

    //Traverse the connections to the goal and print the path taken
    public void printPath( int toGoal) {
        int goalNode = 1;
        if (visited[toGoal]) {
            System.out.println("Completed Path: ");
            for (int t : route(toGoal)) {
                if (t == toGoal) {
                    System.out.print(t);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(t + " -> ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        int goalNode = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter maze file: ");
        String file = scanFile.nextLine();
        Maze maze = new Maze(new File(file));
        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter desired feedback (1 = one soultion, 2 = all): ");
        int inputInt = scanInt.nextInt();
       // maze.toString();
        System.out.println(maze);           
        DFS dfs = new DFS(maze, inputInt);
        dfs.printPath(goalNode);
        }

}
```

I've been looking over it for a while and can't figure out exactly why the data is parsing and being used. Ive altered a few things here and there but have been thrown even more errors. They specifically say

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at DFS.findOne(DFS.java:90)
    at DFS.<init>(DFS.java:22)
    at DFS.main(DFS.java:127)
```

Referencing to the lines of code:

```
visited[node] = true;
findOne(maze, startNode, goalNode);
DFS dfs = new DFS(maze, inputInt);
```

Now essentially im lead to believe that there is no argument being passed, if someone could pin point the problem and lend a hand in helping me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again

EDIT:: Old version of `Maze` class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class Maze {

    static Set<Integer> Nodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer>[] conList;
    int node; //declaring value for my nodes.
    int con; // declaring a connection


    //Constructor takes an int parameter to read through the list of corresponding nodes
    Maze(int node) {
        this.node = node;
        this.con = 0;
        conList = (List<Integer>[]) new List[node];
        for (int index = 0; index < node; index++) {
            conList[index] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }
    }

    //Constructor that takes a String of the maze file 
    public Maze(String mazeFile) {
        this(nodeSize(mazeFile));
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            //Creates a scanner for reading the file and loops through linking the nodes to their connections.
            scan = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));

            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int firstNode = scan.nextInt();
                int secondNode = scan.nextInt();
                addCon(firstNode, secondNode);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        }
    }


    /*Takes String parameter which is the name of the maze file. 
     * Method designed to return the the size of the set of nodes
     */
    public static int nodeSize(String mazeFile) {
        Scanner scanNodeSize;
        try {
            scanNodeSize = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));
          //while scan has more int's left repeat.
            while (scanNodeSize.hasNextInt()) { 
                int firstNode = scanNodeSize.nextInt();
                int secondNode = scanNodeSize.nextInt();
                Nodes.add(firstNode);
                Nodes.add(secondNode);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Nodes.size();
    }

    //Method designed to connect the first and second nodes 
    private void addCon(int firstNode, int secondNode) {
        con++; 
        conList[firstNode].add(secondNode);
        conList[secondNode].add(firstNode);
    }

    //outputs the nodes and their connection's (#remove later?)
    public void print() {

        for (int n = 0; n < node; n++) {
            System.out.print(n + " connected to ");
            for (int w : conList[n]) {
                System.out.print(w + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    //method returns a list, enabling nodes to be easily accessible.
    public Iterable<Integer> getconList(int nodes) {
        return conList[nodes];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an index out of bounds exception at 0. This should lead you to believe that the array has not properly been initialized. You initialize the visited[] array with maze.node however nowhere in your code do we see where this node variable is located. You need to give a proper value to maze.node if you want this to even be runnable.

*EDIT - My above answer is no longer applicable now that we have your previous Maze class which explains why the code will not run.

There are so many things wrong with the code in its current state so I will try and give you some direction here:

Your new way of creating a Maze is to read from the file and connect the 2 points and store them in an Map. The issue with this is that you cannot just get the next element since you have to have the key to get the element. To fix this you should use a different data structure.

```
    public DFS(Maze maze, int inputInt) {
        int startNode = 0;
        int goalNode = 1;
        route = new int[maze.node]; //!!! maze.node isn't a thing anymore
        visited = new boolean[maze.node]; //!!! maze.node isn't a thing anymore
```

You can see that you are trying to access maze.node which use to be a variable of Maze. It no longer is. You need to find a new way of getting a node from Maze. To do this you need to grab the node from your data structure in a different way:

```
        public DFS(Maze maze, int inputInt) {
        int startNode = 0;
        int goalNode = 1;
        route = new int[maze.adjList.getNode()];
        visited = new boolean[maze.adjList.getNode()];
```

You have a lot of options for a different data structure for you adjacency list but something such as this:

http://theoryofprogramming.com/adjacency-list-in-java/

will give you a decent starting point.

Comment: i'll add in my previous Maze class code showing howi previously implemented the maze.node I dont think its possible to implement it the same way with my new Maze class

Comment: @Ben411916 Do you mean that you took that code out? Is the code posted in your question all of the code?

Comment: @Ben411916 If you took out the code that set Maze.node then your current code is unusable.

Comment: any idea's on a work around other than rewriting the whole thing again just to implement my new `maze` class

Comment: I have tried it like this which is the only logical way i can think to do it 
 route = new int[maze.getadjList(node)]; but no joy

Comment: Brilliant thank you for taking the time and giving me a guideline :)